# ext js 4.0 hbox with list and form?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

I am new to extjs 4.0 and trying to make a hbox layout containing a list and a form,but the form is not displaying properly, only labels are visible but textfield is not visible,please rectify the code

```
Ext.define("Screener.view.PharmacyView", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

requires : [ 'Screener.view.Pharmacyform' ],

    xtype: 'pharmacylist',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'hbox',
        title: 'Patient Assignments',
        items: [

                //our patient list is built on the Patients store, and has a title and sort button
                {                   
                    xtype: 'list', 
                    id: 'patientList',

                    itemTpl: '{lastname}, {firstname}',
                    store: Ext.create('Screener.store.Patients',{
                        storeId: 'patientStore'

                    }),

                    items:[{
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        docked: 'top',
                        title: 'Patients',
                        items:[{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Sort',
                            id: 'sortButton',
                            align: 'left'
                        }]
                    }],
                    flex:1,

                },


             {xtype : 'pharmacyform',
             flex:2


             }
                ]
    }

});
```

and the form is as follows

> Ext.define("Screener.view.Pharmacyform", {
>
> ```
>   xtype:'pharmacyform',   extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',    config:{    items: [
>     {
>         xtype: 'textfield',
>         name : 'name',
>         label: 'Name', placeholder: 'nametext'
>     },
>         ]}     });
> ```

Comment: Is it ExtJs4 or Sencha-touch? These are two different frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the alias config to declare your own xtypes I believe, try this

```
Ext.define("Screener.view.Pharmacyform", {
      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
      alias:'widget.pharmacyform',
```

Comment: there was problem with microloader environment,when i am running directly it works fine,thankyou for you help